# Getting error while updating ADT in Eclipse Classic?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I am using Eclipse Classic 3.5 for developing Android apps. But since the last 2 days I am facing a problem while updating my ADT.

When I am opening the eclipse, it says an error to update my ADT to version 14 or above, my current ADT version is 12.

When I am trying to update from Help->check for updates, it is showing

```
The software items you selected may not be valid with your current installation. Do you want to open the wizard anyway to review the selections.
```

Then I click the button "Yes" and then I select the DDMS, Dev Tools, Hierarchy Views, Traceview and click the button "Next". Then it show the following error

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534   (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
Missing requirement: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires   'org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.0' but it could not be found
```

Even I tried to the option "Install new Softwares" by selecting the "ADT Plugin URL", which shows the error saying your DDMS, DevTools, etc... are already installed needs to be updated.

In another way also I tried to update my ADT just by double clicking the "SDK Manager" application icon present inside the Android-sdk-platform, which shows a list of installed and uninstalled files . But I don't think it is a good way as it may take hours of time to be downloaded because of their large size.

Someone please help me, so that I can easily update my ADT.